How to dynamically create aggregate instances with varying base classes?
I need to dynamically create instances of an Aggregate class in C++ which inherits from multiple base classes, where the combination of base classes can vary based on runtime conditions. I want to avoid pre-populating all possible combinations.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve
I have several base classes:
class CharBase
{
    CharBase() { std::cout << "CharBase\n"; }
};

class UnsignedCharBase
{
    UnsignedCharBase() { std::cout << "UnsignedCharBase\n"; }
};

class ShortBase
{
    ShortBase() { std::cout << "ShortBase\n"; }
};

class IntBase
{
    IntBase() { std::cout << "IntBase\n"; }
};

I use the following Aggregate class template to inherit from multiple base classes
template<typename... Bases>
class Aggregate : Bases…
{
    Aggregate() { std::cout << "Aggregate\n"; }
};

My goal is to create instances of the Aggregate classes on demand based on runtime conditions. The expected result is to create an Aggregate instance as if I hardcoded it, for example:
new Aggregate<CharBase, UnsignedCharBase, ShortBase>
new Aggregate<UnsignedCharBase, IntBase>


You stated what you need, but what is your actual question? Templates are processed at compile-time only, not runtime. Also, your Aggregate<...> examples are completely different and unrelated types without a common base class, so they are not interchangable if you are trying to store them in a single pointer variable, for instance.

I understand that templates are processed at compile-time. I'm trying to dynamically decide which combination of base classes to use at runtime obviously, and then create an instance of an Aggregate class that inherits from those base classes.

lets assume you can, how do you plan to use it later?

By parsing some statements from a json file during runtime.

I mean - lets assume that you declared such template and instantiated such class - how will you use it? will you call some methods, pass it somewhere?

I intend to call methods defined in the base classes, pass instances to other functions that expect specific behaviors provided by the base classes, etc.

how will you determine what methods you can call and to which methods you can pass instance of such class?

This sounds like a job for std::tuple.

@Kitiara "I'm trying to dynamically decide which combination of base classes to use at runtime, and then create an instance of an Aggregate class that inherits from those base classes" - Sorry, but C++ simply doesn't work that way. The closest you can get to that is something like this: if (useCharBase && useUnsignedCharBase && useShortBase) { Aggregate<CharBase, UnsignedCharBase, ShortBase> agg; doSomethingWith(agg); } else if (useUnsignedCharBase && useIntBase) { Aggregate<UnsignedCharBase, IntBase> agg; doSomethingWith(agg); } else ... That gets really ugly really quick.

@Kitiara This feels very much like an XY Problem. It would help if you would [edit] your question to show examples of how you expect to be able to use these class instances. However, in this situation, Composition might make more sense than Inheritance.

@IłyaBursov From Json again. What are you getting at ? Type safety ? The Aggregate class template provides type safety by ensuring that only valid methods from the included base classes are callable.

@RemyLebeau I wouldn't have asked this question if i wanted to go with composition. I don't agree calling a problem XY Problem when it is hard to solve.

@PeteBecker Probably. Perhaps a templated tuple with a std::index_sequence involved

@Kitiara try to implement couple combinations just to test and you will see where I'm going

@Kitiara I'm not calling it an XY problem because it is hard. I'm calling it that because that is what I see it as: "you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y." We don't know what your X problem is (what your goal with these classes is), but you seem to think that Y (specifying base classes dynamically at runtime) is the solution, when it can't be since C++ doesn't support that. So you need a different solution. If we knew the problem you want to solve, we can help find a solution.

@RemyLebeau I already have made some progress as we speak, so don't tell me C++ can't do that.

@Kitiara OK, whatever. Good luck with your effort.

Oracle Database generates code on the fly from SQL statements, and compiles that code, and runs it.  Your program could also dynamically generate the code it needs, compile it, and run it, at runtime.

@Eljay I was looking for a C++ solution only, but thanks for the idea though.

My comment was for a C++ solution only, using Oracle as an example of a C++ program that uses a C++ solution only for it's SQL needs.

@Eljay Oh i see, i misunderstood.

One way to turn runtime value to compile value is to use std::variant.
For your case, I would use std::tuple to store the result for "optional" type.
template <typename T>
std::variant<std::tuple<>,
             std::tuple<std::type_identity<T>>>
AsOptionalTypeVar(bool b)
{
    if (b) {
        return std::tuple<std::type_identity<T>>{};
    } else {
        return std::tuple<>{};
    }
}

An Helper trait to transform a tuple into Aggregate
template <typename T> struct to_aggregate;
template <typename... Ts> struct to_aggregate<std::tuple<std::type_identity<Ts>...>>
{
    using type = Aggregate<Ts...>;
};

Then you might let std::visit does the Cartesian product
std::visit(
    [](auto... bases){
        using all_base = decltype(std::tuple_cat(bases...));
        using aggregate = typename to_aggregate<all_base>::type;

        // Use aggregate type as you want
    },
    AsOptionalTypeVar<CharBase>(useCharBase),
    AsOptionalTypeVar<UnsignedCharBase>(useUnsignedCharBase),
    AsOptionalTypeVar<ShortBase>(useShortBase),
    AsOptionalTypeVar<IntBase>(useIntBase)
);

Demo

Yes, it looks like a good solution. The solution i propose were pre-populating all the combinations automatically but not manually. However that comes with a cost and what you are proposing is much better, thanks.

If you add 5-6 more classes, the compiler start to use 20 gb ram and crashes.

2**9 is 512 combinations (msvc seems to not support it, gcc/clang does Demo) I got time exceeded for 2 ** 10 (= 1024) Demo.

I dunno what happens under the hood but having a limit of 512 is funny in 2024. You can write all that manually and it's gonna be fine, but it's not ok if you make the compiler calculate it, interesting. My own solution also suffers the same thing which i was referring as cost

I overcome the limitation in my previous answer. You can see the new answer below.
New Answer:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

class IAggregate
{
public:
    virtual ~IAggregate() = default;
};

template<typename... Bases>
class Aggregate : public IAggregate, public Bases...
{
public:
    Aggregate() { std::cout << "Aggregate\n"; }
    virtual ~Aggregate() override = default;
};

// Base classes for demonstration
class CharBase
{
public:
    CharBase() { std::cout << "CharBase display\n"; }
};

class UnsignedCharBase
{
public:
    UnsignedCharBase() { std::cout << "UnsignedCharBase display\n"; }
};

class ShortBase
{
public:
    ShortBase() { std::cout << "ShortBase display\n"; }
};

class IntBase
{
public:
    IntBase() { std::cout << "IntBase display\n"; }
};

class FloatBase
{
public:
    FloatBase() { std::cout << "FloatBase display\n"; }
};

// List of all base classes
using AllBases                 = std::tuple<CharBase, UnsignedCharBase, ShortBase, IntBase, FloatBase>;
constexpr std::size_t NumBases = std::tuple_size_v<AllBases>;

// Custom constexpr bitset class auto configured BITS_PER_WORD
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t BITS_PER_WORD>
class ConstexprBitset
{
public:
    constexpr ConstexprBitset()
        : bits {}
    {
    }

    constexpr void set(std::size_t pos)
    {
        if (pos >= N)
            throw std::out_of_range("Bit position out of range");
        bits[pos / BITS_PER_WORD] |= (1ULL << (pos % BITS_PER_WORD));
    }

    constexpr bool test(std::size_t pos) const
    {
        if (pos >= N)
            throw std::out_of_range("Bit position out of range");
        return (bits[pos / BITS_PER_WORD] & (1ULL << (pos % BITS_PER_WORD))) != 0;
    }

private:
    std::array<unsigned long long, (N + BITS_PER_WORD - 1) / BITS_PER_WORD> bits;
};

constexpr std::size_t calculateOptimalBitsPerWord(std::size_t numBases)
{
    return (numBases + 63) / 64; // Each unsigned long long covers 64 bits
}

constexpr std::size_t OptimalBitsPerWord = calculateOptimalBitsPerWord(NumBases);

template<int Mask, typename Tuple, typename Enable = void, typename... Types>
struct TypeExtractor;

template<int Mask, typename Tuple, typename... Types>
struct TypeExtractor<Mask, Tuple, std::enable_if_t<Mask == 0>, Types...>
{
    using type = Aggregate<Types...>;
};

template<int Mask, typename Tuple, typename... Types>
struct TypeExtractor<Mask, Tuple, std::enable_if_t<Mask != 0>, Types...>
{
    static constexpr ConstexprBitset<NumBases, OptimalBitsPerWord> mask = []()
    {
        ConstexprBitset<NumBases, OptimalBitsPerWord> bs;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NumBases; ++i)
            if (Mask & (1 << i))
                bs.set(i);
        return bs;
    }();

    static constexpr std::size_t highestBit = []()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = NumBases; i > 0; --i)
            if (mask.test(i - 1))
                return i - 1;
        throw std::out_of_range("No bits are set");
    }();

    using BaseType = std::tuple_element_t<highestBit, Tuple>;
    using type = typename TypeExtractor<Mask & ~(1 << highestBit), Tuple, void, Types..., BaseType>::type;
};

template<int Mask>
using ExtractTypes = typename TypeExtractor<Mask, AllBases>::type;

using AggregatePtr = std::unique_ptr<IAggregate>;
template<int Mask>
AggregatePtr createAggregateInstance()
{
    return std::make_unique<ExtractTypes<Mask>>();
}

// Helper to create a map of factory functions
template<int... Masks>
constexpr auto createFactoryMap(std::integer_sequence<int, Masks...>)
{
    using FuncType = AggregatePtr (*)();
    return std::array<FuncType, sizeof...(Masks)> {{&createAggregateInstance<Masks>...}};
}

// The factory map consists of AllBases tuple
constexpr auto factoryMap = createFactoryMap(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 1 << NumBases> {});

AggregatePtr createAggregate(int mask)
{
    if (mask < factoryMap.size())
        return factoryMap[mask]();
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        auto instance = createAggregate(i);
        if (!instance)
            std::cout << "Invalid combination for input: " << i << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

Live
Old Answer:
Here it is the solution i managed to come up with. The only limitation here is the highestSetBit. I tried to get rid of that but i couldn't, it is appreciated if someone can figure that out.
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

class IAggregate
{
public:
    virtual ~IAggregate() = default;
};

template<typename... Bases>
class Aggregate : public IAggregate, public Bases...
{
public:
    Aggregate() { std::cout << "Aggregate\n"; }
    virtual ~Aggregate() override = default;
};

class CharBase
{
public:
    static constexpr int Mask = 1 << 0;
    CharBase() { std::cout << "CharBase display\n"; }
};

class UnsignedCharBase
{
public:
    static constexpr int Mask = 1 << 1;
    UnsignedCharBase() { std::cout << "UnsignedCharBase display\n"; }
};

class ShortBase
{
public:
    static constexpr int Mask = 1 << 2;
    ShortBase() { std::cout << "ShortBase display\n"; }
};

class IntBase
{
public:
    static constexpr int Mask = 1 << 3;
    IntBase() { std::cout << "IntBase display\n"; }
};

// List of all base classes
using AllBases = std::tuple<CharBase, UnsignedCharBase, ShortBase, IntBase>;

constexpr int highestSetBit(const int mask) // This is the only limitation in this design
{
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i)
        if (mask & (1 << i))
            return i;
    return -1; // should never reach here for valid masks
}

template<int Mask, typename Tuple, typename Enable = void, typename... Types>
struct TypeExtractor;

template<int Mask, typename Tuple, typename... Types>
struct TypeExtractor<Mask, Tuple, std::enable_if_t<Mask == 0>, Types...>
{
    using type = Aggregate<Types...>;
};

template<int Mask, typename Tuple, typename... Types>
struct TypeExtractor<Mask, Tuple, std::enable_if_t<Mask != 0>, Types...>
{
    static constexpr int highestBit = highestSetBit(Mask);
    using BaseType                  = std::tuple_element_t<highestBit, Tuple>;
    using type                      = typename TypeExtractor<Mask & ~(1 << highestBit), Tuple, void, Types..., BaseType>::type;
};

template<int Mask>
using ExtractTypes = typename TypeExtractor<Mask, AllBases>::type;

using AggregatePtr = std::unique_ptr<IAggregate>;

template<int Mask>
AggregatePtr createAggregateInstance()
{
    return std::make_unique<ExtractTypes<Mask>>();
}

// Helper to create a map of factory functions
template<int... Masks>
constexpr auto createFactoryMap(std::integer_sequence<int, Masks...>)
{
    using FuncType = AggregatePtr (*)();
    return std::array<FuncType, sizeof...(Masks)> {{&createAggregateInstance<Masks>...}};
}

// The factory map consist of AllBases tuple
constexpr auto factoryMap = createFactoryMap(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 1 << std::tuple_size_v<AllBases>> {});

AggregatePtr createAggregate(int mask)
{
    if (mask < factoryMap.size())
        return factoryMap[mask]();
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        auto instance = createAggregate(i);
        if (!instance)
            std::cout << "Invalid combination for input: " << i << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

Live

so, technically you created instance of empty IAggregate, do you plan to cast it to actually use?

@IłyaBursov No it is casted back to IAggregate. If you check the output, you can clearly see the Aggregate is created with the base classes along with it.

variable instance is pointer to IAggregate, can you show example of its usage?

@IłyaBursov The instance itself can register this into a container with an id or something else. There are endless possibilities.

even if you register it somewhere - you still will have to cast, which eliminates all compile time safety

@IłyaBursov Create a pure virtual function that returns tuple. Override it from the Aggregate and return tuple<Bases...> then you use it to cast. It's pretty simple actually

ok, so you do plan to use cast, that's the answer to my question
